# Linear programming polyhedron and recession direction

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $X=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1-x_2+x_3\leq 1, -x_1+2x_2\leq 4, x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0\}$, 
does $X$ have any recession directions? why ?